# Add to <div class="ui button"> to :button Capybara selector

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

I have a Rails web application which uses [FomanticUI](https://fomantic-ui.com/elements/button.html) for styling. I have quite a few buttons like

```html
<div class="ui button">
  Text
</div>
```

I realise that I can technically use `<button>` or `<a>` elements, I like the fact that I don't need to worry about having to call `preventDefault()` or `stopPropagation()`, or that it could submit a `<form>` by accident when I'm catching the click in a JS handler.

So, with that being said, I'm wanting to just call `#click_link_or_button` in Capybara to always find the "button" - regardless of it's element class.

At first I created a very naive method:

```rb
def click_link_or_button(locator = nil, **options)
  super
rescue Capybara::ElementNotFound
  # Fallback to FomanticUI Button
  find(".button", **options.merge({text: locator})).click
end
```

However, this makes it very slow because `super` implicitly waits for up to `Capybara.default_max_wait_time`, before then moving onto the `find(".button")`

I had a look at the definition of the [`:link_or_button` selector](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/selector/definition/link_or_button.rb) for something with an "or" (i.e. button or div.button).

I made it as far as:

```rb
Capybara.add_selector(:button_class) do
  xpath do |locator, **|
    xpath = XPath.descendant(:div)
    xpath = builder(xpath).add_attribute_conditions(class: 'button')

    xpath
  end
end

Capybara.add_selector(:link_or_button, locator_type: [String, Symbol]) do
  label 'link, button or button class'
  xpath do |locator, **options|
    [
      expression_for(:link, locator, **options),
      expression_for(:button, locator, **options),
      expression_for(:button_class, nil, **options.merge(exact_text: locator)) # Text doesn't work here
    ].reduce(:union)
  end

  ...
end
```

However, as you can see in my comment, for some reason it doesn't seem to pass along the text option to `button_class`. It worked when I would use `find(:link_or_button, text: 'Continue')`, but when I just called `click_link_or_button('Continue')` the text option would be lost, and thus would return multiple elements.

I had a look into adding the expression into the XPath statement but got stumped as sometimes I have a `<span>` inside the `div.button` for styling. It was all starting to get too complicated.

My current poor-man's solution is:

```rb
# Attempt to click an element immediately ... and then wait like usual
def click_link_or_button(locator = nil, **options)
  if el=safe_find(:css, 'div.button, a.button', **options.merge(text: locator, wait: 0.2))
    Rails.logger.debug "Found div.button within 0.2s"
    el.click
  elsif el=safe_find(:link_or_button, locator, **options.merge(wait: 0.2))
    Rails.logger.debug "Found :link_or_button within 0.2s"
    el.click
  elsif el=safe_find(:css, 'div.button, a.button', **options.merge(text: locator, wait: Capybara.default_max_wait_time-0.4))
    Rails.logger.debug "Found div.button within waiting #{Capybara.default_max_wait_time-0.4}}"
    el.click
  else
    # Fall back to Capybara::Node::Actions#click_link_or_button with a default wait time of Capybara.default_max_wait_time
    Rails.logger.debug "Falling back to #click_link_or_button"
    super
  end
end

# Attempts to find, but returns nil rather than throws an exception for ease of use in #click_button
def safe_find(type, locator = nil, **options)
  find(type, locator, **options)
rescue Capybara::ElementNotFound => e
  nil
end
```

However, this introduces a lot of complexity for something which seems so simple, and makes it wait for a while doing nothing sometimes. I would like a single query which has a timeout of `Capybara.default_max_wait_time`.

So, does anyone know how I can add the definition of `div.button` to Capybara's definition of what makes a `:button_or_link`?! I feel like I'm over-engineering the solution here